# How to control volume of music based on "Now Playing"?

Tags: macos, music, automation, spotify, sound-volume

I'd like the Mac to mute itself when there's an ad on Spotify. It comes in a pair, 30 seconds each. I now have to hit mute button, then guess if a minute is over yet and then unmute it. Solid distraction.

I think that this info: "Advertisement" in music title could be used. But I don't know if it is accessible by any means in AppleScript.

Some task/ process/ job which I turn on while opening Spotify, which would be monitoring the Song title and then trigger mute and unmute after 60 seconds would do.

Please get me started on this.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps purchasing Spotify Premium? :-) [This site](https://www.tunefab.com/spotify/block-ads-on-spotify-without-premium.html) may help, but my work firewall says it has an invalid certificate and won't let me go through. There a re several such 'block Spotify ads' sites out there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do it, open Script Editor click on Choose File > Open Dictionary > Select Spotify. You should have something like this : https://i.imgur.com/sFoFTSH.png

Comment: @IconDaemon I like ads, but just muted ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a simple solution. Saved this script & put it in user scripts folder.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set volume 0
    delay 30
    set volume 2
end tell
```

[image]